# Azure DevOps - Test Run Management, revert run outcome

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We are currently checking the test plan module on our Azure Devops server and I'm facing an issue that the community may help.
According to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505726/rerunning-failed-test-step-resets-entire-test-case.html) once a test run has been marked as failed or blocked there is no way to resume the test once the raised defects have been resolved. You either have to mark the test run as paused (so as to be granted the "resume" option) or reset the whole test to active in which case you loose all your progress and need to start over. Two questions:

1. This "workaround" works as long as you are careful and save the test run as paused. Otherwise if a failed step exists the run is saved as failed. Once this is done I have found no way of changing it to "paused" so as to get the resume option. Is there a way I'm missing?
2. In the test list under a specific suite you get the current test run outcome and state of test case. In case of "Paused" you don't have a way to know if the test execution is paused or you are utilizing the aforementioned workaround (e.g. a bug is registered). I cannot see a way that I could enhance the test run with some information that would signal this (there is no wit template I have found) on the grid. So is the standard query module (bringing testcases and associated bugs with state) the only way?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, if the test case is on status Failed and you retest the test case, all test steps need to be redone. Also there is no resume-button. This is **by design**. For now, set the status to Paused can resume the test, but it cannot truly reflect the result. As far as I know, there is no other way.

You could add your request for this feature(For example: when status = Failed/Block, the restore button is enable) on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

For the second question, as workaround , you can also add tags to paused test cases for labeling.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Sorry for the confusion on the 2nd question, posted image on the original post. So the only way to know if the testcase is paused due to a bug is having setup a query that will list the testcases and associated bugs

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As workaround , you can also [add tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c9Q7.png) to paused test cases for labeling.

Comment: That will have to do. Thanks